# What is the name of the special method responsible for `if obj:` statement in an object class which does not contain __boo__ method in python

Tags: python, if-statement, methods, magic-methods

I have created a custom object that contains `__bool__` special method as follows:

```
class CustomObject:
   def __init__(self, value):
       self.value = value
   def __bool__(self):
       print("This is from the __bool__ method")
       return True
obj = CustomObject(10)
if obj:
    print("Inside if")
```

output:

```
This is from the __bool__ method
Inside if
```

`if` statement calls the `__bool__` special method. However, in the following code, the custom model does not contain the `__bool__` special method but still, the condition of the `if` statement is True:

```
class CustomObject:
   def __init__(self, value):
       self.value = value

obj = CustomObject(10)
print(dir(obj))
if obj:
    print("Inside if")
```

output:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'value']
Inside if
```

So my question is, which of the special methods in the upper section is called by the `if` statement?

Comment: If an object doesn't have a `__bool__()` method, it's always truthy.

Comment: @Barmar
You mean it happens inside the `if` function? If an object does not have `__bool__` simply it considers that's true as the following
```
if not hasattr(obj, "__bool__"):
    return True
```

Comment: There's a general mechanism for converting an object to a boolean, it's used by the `bool()` function and all the conditional operators. In all cases they treat an object as truthy by default.

Comment: Just use `print(bool(obj))` and you'll see.

Comment: @Barmar inaccurate, you forgot `__len__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) on `__bool__`:

> Called to implement truth value testing and the built-in operation
> `bool()`; should return False or True. When this method is not defined,
> `__len__()` is called, if it is defined, and the object is considered true if its result is nonzero. If a class defines neither `__len__()`
> nor `__bool__()`, all its instances are considered true.

In other words, if `__bool__` doesn't exist, we check `__len__() != 0`. If `__len__` doesn't exist, the answer is always `True`.